# Find mapping between amino acid index from PDB files and sequence

Tags: python, sequence, pdb

I am a beginner in python programming. What I am trying to do is the following:

I have a sequence of amino acids (including gaps) and a corresponding PDB file. The numbering of amino acids in the PDB file does not match the numbering of the amino acids in the sequence list. I want to find the index of each amino acid entries in the PDB file and find the corresponding index in the sequence.

Here is the sequence:`-LLPYFDF----DVPRNLTVTVGQT-GFLHCRVERLGDK-----DVSWIRKR----------DLHILTAGGTTYTSDQRFQVLRP---------------------------------------DGSANWTLQIKYPQPRDSGVYECQINTEP-KMSLSYTFNVVE-IVDPKFSSPIVNMTAPVGRDAFLTCVVQDLGPYKVAWLRVDTQTILTIQNHVITKNQRIGIANSEH---KTWTMRIKDIKESDKGWYMCQINTDPMKSQMGYLDVV----`

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import pylab as pyl
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import re
import argparse
import glob

def parseArgs():
 """Parse command line arguments"""

  try:
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
       description = 'Read and extract items from input PDB file')

      parser.add_argument('-i',
                        '--input',
                        action='store',
                        required=True,
                        help='input PDB file in standard format')

   except:
        print ("An exception occurred with argument parsing. Check your provided options.")
        traceback.print_exc()


   return parser.parse_args()

# Reads a PDB file and returns the residue name and coordinates for 
# each C-alpha atom
# (the input argument for this routine is the pdb file name.)

def get_coordinates_PDB(File_In):
    try:
        fl = open(File_In,'r')
    except:
        print('Could not open input file {0}'.format(File_In))
        sys.exit()
    Res = []
    Points = []
    #Getting from a PDB file

    for line in fl:
        if not(line.startswith('ATOM')):
            continue
        elif (line[13:15] != 'CA'):
            continue
        resname = line[17:20]
        xyz = re.findall('[-+]?\d+\.\d+', line)
        tmp = np.zeros(3)
        Res.append(resname)
        tmp[0] = float(xyz[0])
        tmp[1] = float(xyz[1])
        tmp[2] = float(xyz[2])
        Points.append(tmp)
     fl.close()
     return Points, Res


def main():
  """Read and parse a provided PDB file."""


  #Parse arguments
  args = parseArgs()

  File_In = args.input

  print(get_coordinates_PDB(File_In))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This outputs the x,y,z coordinates and the amino acids in the PDB file. However, I am stalled at this point.

I would much appreciate if someone could help me with implementing the rest.

Comment: Some suggestions: proofread your question. The indentation is messed up and that's very important in Python.  The phrase "enter code here" appears in the listing.  Keep in mind that the readers of this site are programming experts but they probably don't understand a protein sequence listing (I don't, and I took molecular biology in college).  You say: "if the first entry in the PDB file is Alanine, I want to find the corresponding index of Alaline in the sequence list". I think you need to explain, step by step, with terminology from math and logic, what procedure will do that.

Comment: @Paul Cornelius: I apologize for the omission. I have edited my text and the indentation.